# Google Cloud Vision API - You have no permission to use the requested API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-apis-explorer

I am new to using Google Cloud Vision API. I am following the documentation here and I get error in step 3. How should I fix it?

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart-client-libraries

[image]

After I click on the `enable the API` I see what follows as an error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This may be a funny error of session variables on the console.

Notice that in your screenshot, see where it says "Select a project" ?

The error message is weird because it says you don't have permission, but I think the real problem may be that you haven't selected a project yet. Hit that button and select one of your projects where you're an Owner, and then try Enabling the API from the button again (and/or you can go to the API Library, search for the Vision API and enable it from there).

Comment: somehow it works for me with no problem with the API client in terminal. I'll get back to you later but do you know why score could be larger than 1? here , Paul Ryan has a score of 13.30 (actually that's the entity in image) but thought they are supposed to be under 1!
Score      : 13.303500175476074
 Description: Paul Ryan

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following... did you use an image of Paul Ryan in what you're testing with the Vision API? You probably want to start a second SO question for that specific if the problem was selecting the project to get you on to the next step since the two are unrelated issues.

Comment: Gotcha, yeah. For specific questions now about the API itself and results, I'd start a fresh SO question focusing just on that. Otherwise you have multiple unrelated questions in a single SO question which will just get it closed. :( I know it's all related to what you're working on, but the answers will be very different, so it won't be searchable later if two subjects like that are part of the same question.